# Springboot is not loading application properties in cloud environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a weird case, I am currently working on upgrading my application with new jars. However after updating with New Jars. My deployment in cloud environment stopped working. It works absolutely fine in my local.

This jar has its own springboot configurations but I believe it should not affect my changes.

When I print all the environment variables, I observed that my application.yml is not getting loaded which is causing this issue but I have no idea why ? Has one one come across similar situation.

Before upgrade: Springboot property source:

```
OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='Config resource 'file [/etc/config/application.yaml]' via location 'optional:file:/etc/config/application.yaml''}
OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='appDefaultConfig [classpath:/old-defaults.yml]'}
OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='appDefaultConfig [classpath:/old-defaults.yml] (document #0)'}
```

After upgrade: Springboot property source:

```
OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='appDefaultConfig [classpath:/new-defaults.yml]#default (document #1)'}
OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='appDefaultConfig [classpath:/new-defaults.yml] (document #0)'}
```

I see that 'config resource ' in OriginTrackedMapPropertySource is missing after upgrade.
Also, I observed that spring active profile which was displaying earlier is now showing empty.

I am using spring boot 2.7.4 Java 17 version.

Comment: It would appear that application.yaml has now disappeared as a file resource. It won't do you any harm to dump the value of the classpath so you know what it is

Comment: The issue here is that, it is completely missing to read the application.yml file. The first line which starts with Config resource is missing

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't added anything to my last comment, but rather repeated it. Firstly, where is the resource *now* that contains the configuration you need?

Comment: The resource is available in this location:  'file [/etc/config/application.yaml]'

Comment: Why not try adding that manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, The issue seem to be with the way I set spring profile in my mvn command. Previously it was set to                 -Dspring.config.location=optional:classpath:/,optional:file:/etc/config/application.yaml

I changed to
-Dspring.config.location=file:/etc/config/application.yaml and it started working. However, I could not figure out the reason behind it.